# XLOOKUP with multiple criteria always gives array size error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I can never get XLOOKUP to work with multiple criteria. All I ever get is "Array arguments to XLOOKUP are of different size" no mater what data set I use.

Eventually I want to use this in a work center/product type lookup that will be something like "Metal work & Soldering" to get something like items per FTE day = 20

Working in Google Sheets. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3nJw.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbUqY.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwkn3.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPMDw.jpg)

Column A
Header: Item 1
Ships
Cars
Airplanes
Motorcycles

Column B
Header: Item 2
Water
Roads
Sky
Roads

Column C:
Header: Price
300
50
120
20

Criteria 1/Cell F1: Cars
Criteria 2/Cell F2: Roads

Formula: =XLOOKUP(F1&F2,A2:A5&B2:B5,C2:C5)

Desired result: 50
Actual result: #N/A Array arguments to XLOOKUP are of different size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `arrayformula` or `index` wrapped around the 2 columns you were concatenating `A2:A5&B2:B5` otherwise the result is just goin' to be `A2&B2` which obviously has just one row data compared to `C2:C5` with 4 rows of data thus resulting in ***different size error***

try: `xlookup(F1&F2,index(A2:A5&B2:B5),C2:C5,)`

Comment: Oh boy, talk about a early morning caffeine deficiency error. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter either index/match.
What I am trying to understand if it is a "limit" of Gsheet (that does not support that XLOOKUP function "Multiple Criteria Boolean Expressions", like Excel does instead or it actually supports it, but there should be a different phrasing method..)

Comment: Please observe that Stack Exchange sites are not "help forums" nor "discussion boards" but **wiki** sites that use the Q&A format. Your post does not look like an answer to the question that was asked. See [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).